# Spring Request Mapping call one Function to check User

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, request-mapping

I have different mappings that start with \mobile or contain \mobile. Is there a way to catch all these mappings?

My Mappings are:

```
\mobile\login.mvc

\mobile\profile\details.mvc

\secure\mobile\profile\edit.mvc
```

Now I want that for all "\mobile" mappings one function oder mapping is called, and then the call mapping.

Background: I want to check with every call, whether the user is logged in and sign him if necessary. But I would not query at every mapping the parameters username and password but all in one place.

Comment: You need to look at the spring-security project http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate user in every controller then Spring AOP will be a good choice. 
You can write a single authentication method and invoke it before controller using AOP.
This might help http://tedone.typepad.com/blog/2011/05/using-aop-easily-with-aspectj-and-spring.html